# возобновление работы addEventListener после removeEventListener

Tags: javascript, события, parallax

Здравствуйте, имеется данный код.
После того, как элемент с фоном скрылся - смещения фона не происходит.

```
  var lastCall = Date.now();
  var clouds = document.getElementsByClassName('header-clouds')[0];    
  window.addEventListener('scroll', parlx);

  function parlx() {
    if (Date.now() - lastCall >= THROTTLE_TIMEOUT) {
      clouds.style.backgroundPositionX = parseInt(document.body.scrollTop * -0.5) + 'px';
      if (clouds.getBoundingClientRect().bottom <= 0) {
        console.log('stop parallaxscroll');
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', parlx);
      }
    }
    lastCall = Date.now();
  }
```

Но после того, как я удалил событие через removEventListener- оно удалилось навсегда. То есть когда я делаю прокрутку обратно вверх - addEventListener не срабатывает. И смещения фона картинки заново не происходит.

Comment: "когда я делаю ... - addEventListener не срабатывает." - а Вы его снова вызвали?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может, просто добавить условие?

```
function parlx() {
  if (Date.now() - lastCall >= THROTTLE_TIMEOUT &&
      clouds.getBoundingClientRect().bottom > 0) {
    clouds.style.backgroundPositionX = parseInt(document.body.scrollTop * -0.5) + 'px';
  }
  lastCall = Date.now();
}
```